# Atributos de segurança em web service

Tags: c#, web-service, soap, asmx

Dá para usar o `AuthorizeAttribute` em webservice asmx, soap ou rest? E atributos customizados, como o abaixo (apenas exemplo)?

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class |
                       System.AttributeTargets.Struct)
]
public class Author : System.Attribute
{
    private string name;
    public double version;

    public Author(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        version = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para Web Services, o correto é [definir um módulo HTTP que trate cabeçalhos SOAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z52by6a(v=vs.80).aspx).

A seguir, é preciso definir um *web method* que faça este tratamento do cabeçalho, aí sim usando os atributos já conhecidos.

A priori serve tanto para ASMX quanto WCF.

Abaixo um exemplo de uso com um `RoleProvider` ([ensino a implementar aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+roleprovider)):

```
public class SecureWebService : WebService{
  public Authentication authentication;

  [WebMethod]
  [SoapHeader("authentication")]
  public string UsuarioValido() {
    if (User.IsInRole("Cliente"))
      return "Usuário é um cliente";

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      return "Usuário validado";

    return "Não autenticado";
  }
}
```